# Creating Zip archive in memory while reading a pdf file gives error "The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, memorystream, c#-ziparchive

I have a simple method that tries to generate zip archive by reading a pdf file saved on disk.
However, it gives me "The compressed (zipped) folder is invalid".

Here is my method:

```
        public ActionResult ExportToPdf()
        {

            string fileName = "test.pdf";
            string fileNameZip = "Export.zip";

            byte[] fileBytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(@"C:\Users\dkhalil\Downloads\dummy.pdf");
            byte[] compressedBytes = null;
            using (var outStream = new MemoryStream())
            {
                using (var archive = new ZipArchive(outStream, ZipArchiveMode.Create, true))
                {
                    var fileInArchive = archive.CreateEntry(fileName, CompressionLevel.Optimal);
                    using (var entryStream = fileInArchive.Open())
                    {
                        using (var fileToCompressStream = new MemoryStream(fileBytes))
                        {
                            fileToCompressStream.CopyTo(entryStream);
                        }

                    }
                }
                compressedBytes = outStream.ToArray();
            }
            return File(compressedBytes, MediaTypeNames.Application.Octet, fileNameZip);
        }
```

I have spent hours trying to figure out what's wrong with my code.
Is the archive corrupt or could there be any other issues with my code.
Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: I can't see any way this error should happen. On which line are you getting it?

Comment: Side note: there are some efficiencies you can make: open the `dummy` file using `FileStream` instead of a byte array, and copy that straight in. Return `outStream` to `File` instead of writing it to `compressedBytes`. If you really needed to have it as a byte array you can use `outStream.GetBuffer` along with the length.

Comment: So it turns out, the project was inheriting a BaseController class which had a whitespace filter, by removing that filter, the code works fine. I still don't understand exactly how, but it works.